# NETSH WLAN - Connected to which network?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, netsh

With `NETSH WLAN` one can find the list of interfaces, connections, settings, costs etc. But how do I find the most basic information:

- How to find to which network (SSID) I am connected to (as shown in GUI) ?

These do not help:

- `netsh wlan show profiles`
- `netsh wlan show profiles name=*`
- `netsh wlan show interfaces`
- ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just found the answer to this. Just need to use **`netsh wlan show interfaces`** command. This will show all interfaces (Wi-Fi devices/cards - as shown in *Network Connections*). For example, when not connected to any WiFi, it will show:

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : WiFi
    Description            : D-Link DWA-132 Wireless N USB Adapter(rev.B)
    GUID                   : b023475e-7b92-4714-9cb2-0d15bc7c182b
    Physical address       : 78:54:2e:df:1b:01
    State                  : disconnected
    Radio status           : Hardware On
                             Software On

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

But, after connecting to a Wi-Fi SSID, it shows:

```
There is 1 interface on the system:

    Name                   : WiFi
    Description            : D-Link DWA-132 Wireless N USB Adapter(rev.B)
    GUID                   : b023475e-7b92-4714-9cb2-0d15bc7c182b
    Physical address       : 78:54:2e:df:1b:01
    State                  : connected
    SSID                   : YourSSID
    BSSID                  : 06:18:0a:7a:c0:d4
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : 802.11n
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Connection mode        : Profile
    Channel                : 11
    Receive rate (Mbps)    : 144
    Transmit rate (Mbps)   : 144
    Signal                 : 100%
    Profile                : TheProfileName

    Hosted network status  : Not available
```

Where the entry **Profile: TheProfileName** and **SSID: YourSSID** shows the profile/SSID you are connected to. If there are multiple Wi-Fi devices, the details will be shown appropriately.